# Check email in shell. And make it look good

Tags: perl, shell, email, variables, terminal

I want to output the email information as

(Who it's from)
      (Subject)
Here's the code i found on the internet

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -u username --silent "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom" | perl -ne 'print "\t" if /<name>/;  print "$2\n" if /<(title|name)>(.*)<\/\1>/;')
```

however this isn't the format i want it and i don't know any perl. 
i was wondering if i could either output the perl information to a shell variable so i can edit the layout. or output the perl information to a txt file and then edit it then. by edit i mean change the order of it so its name, subject rather than subject, name. Any help will be a  big help. I may be completely wrong because i don't know any perl.

Comment: Googling `perl check gmail` gives this as the most recent article: [`Check GMail with IMAP Client [PERL]`](http://massivelayer.com/2013/04/check-gmail-with-imap-client-perl/)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are logged in to Gmail, `https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom` will give you an dump of the latest few messages in your inbox. This is in XML (Atom) format and you can use whatever you want to read it. You can see what the raw data looks like by going there in a browser.

The code you have found uses Perl to parse and display a more readable form of this data. You are certainly not obligated to use Perl if you don't know it, so you can use whatever programming language you are familiar with.